# C++: Simple error I cannot spot! C2146

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, syntax-error

Pretty new to C++, I have been following the intermediate tutorials at 3DBuzz.com, and trying to experiment with their tasks.

Current tutorial is on classes: http://www.3dbuzz.com/vbforum/sv_showvideo.php?v=37

I am trying to overload the &operator << to output my 'Point' as a stream when I want. The relevant part of the video starts at **39:00**.

As far as I can tell my code is syntactically identical (though I am new so I'm probably missing something) but I get the error:

**1>c:\users\jack\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\myfirstgame\myfirstgame\main.cpp(88): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'myPoint**

I realise that I declare the instance Point &myPoint in the operator overload function.. but I don't know where else I could do it so the compiler knows what it is.. if that makes sense.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

class Point
{
public:
Point(float f_x = 0.0, float f_y = 0.0, float f_z = 0.0);

~Point();

void SetXYZ(float X, float Y, float Z);
void SetX(float X);
void SetY(float Y);
void SetZ(float Z);

void GetXYZ(float &X, float &Y, float &Z);
float GetX();
float GetY();
float GetZ();
private:

float x, y, z;

protected:

};

Point::Point(float f_x, float f_y, float f_z)
{
cout << "Constructor with ARGUMENTS!" << endl;

x = f_x;
y = f_y;
z = f_z;
}

void Point::GetXYZ(float &X, float &Y, float &Z)
{
X = GetX();
Y = GetY();
Z = GetZ();
}
float Point::GetX()
{
return x;
}

float Point::GetY()
 {
return y;
 }

float Point::GetZ()
{
return z;
}

void Point::SetXYZ(float X,float Y, float Z)
{
SetX(X);
SetY(Y);
SetZ(Z);
}
void Point::SetX(float X)
{
x = X;
}

void Point::SetY(float Y)
{
y = Y;
}

void Point::SetZ(float Z)
{
z = Z;
}

Point::~Point()
{
cout << "We're in the destructor" << endl;
}

 ostream &operator <<(ostream &stream, Point &myPoint)
{
stream << myPoint.GetX() << " " << myPoint.GetY() << " " myPoint.GetZ();
return stream;
}

void main()
{
float x, y, z; //Declaring floats for use in GetXYZ()

Point myLocation (1,2,-1); //Creating instance and using Point(...) function
cout << myLocation.GetX() << myLocation.GetY() << myLocation.GetZ() <<endl; // Getting xyz values and printing

myLocation.SetXYZ(2,3,-4); //Testing SetXYZ function
cout << myLocation.GetX() << myLocation.GetY() << myLocation.GetZ() <<endl; // Getting xyz values and printing


myLocation.GetXYZ(x, y, z);
cout << x << " " << y << " " << z << endl;

cout << myLocation;


    system("PAUSE");
}
```

**EDIT: Unbelievable response! Love this site already. Thanks everyone who spotted this ^^**

Comment: I believe you need to declare it as a "friend" in order for it to work. Also, the Point& parameter should be declared const. Also, unless this is code for an embedded system main() must return int or your code will not compile on a C++ compiler.

Comment: If this tutorial actually recommends `using namespace std;` it is a bad tutorial.

Comment: @Lundin: The operator does not access any nonpublic members, so it does not need to be a friend.

Comment: @ Lundin Ah the old "int main()".. so this tutorial uses void main(), is that cause it's just a tutorial and not for use? I thought the 'int' or 'void' part was what was returned, so the 'main' didn't need to return anything for console stuff?

Comment: @ Space_C0wb0y Why is using namespace std; bad?? So far it's been in every piece of code I've written =/

Comment: @JackyX On a hosted system, that is Windows, Linux, Unix, Mac etc, main() must return int in the C++ language. On a hostless system (no OS present, or your program is the OS itself), it should return void. Non-standard compilers allow void main() for hosted systems, but a C++ compiler will not allow it. I suspect that your tutorial is not of top-notch quality.

Comment: Thanks guys. I think the tutorial aims to cover enough for you to get coding yourself and learn the semantics yourself on the fly.. it's nicely done but I can see it has its shortcomings.

Edit: Damn enter saves the post! 
I also looked up why using namespace std; is bad practise and that was enlightening, so cheers for that too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing `<<` in :

```
stream << myPoint.GetX() << " " << myPoint.GetY() << " " myPoint.GetZ();
                                                       ^^
```

Comment: <3 Thank You! I'm such a noob ^^

Comment: @ Space_C0wboy I won't, but it's given me a time limit :P 3 mins more..!

Answer (score 0):

At line 88 you should add << before `myPoint.GetZ();`

Your code:

```
stream << myPoint.GetX() << " " << myPoint.GetY() << " " myPoint.GetZ();
```

Correction:

```
stream << myPoint.GetX() << " " << myPoint.GetY() << " " << myPoint.GetZ();
```

Answer (score 0):

See the difference in between these two?

```
stream << myPoint.GetX() << " " << myPoint.GetY() << " " myPoint.GetZ();
stream << myPoint.GetX() << " " << myPoint.GetY() << " " << myPoint.GetZ();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem: `stream << myPoint.GetX() << " " << myPoint.GetY() << " " myPoint.GetZ();` You are missing `<<` between the last `" "` and the last `myPoint`.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
ostream &operator <<(ostream &stream, Point &myPoint) { stream << myPoint.GetX() << " " << myPoint.GetY() << " "<< myPoint.GetZ(); return stream; }
```

Note the extra "<<" before myPoint.GetZ();